# notifyDataSetChanged() without freezing mainthread

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I have listview and custom adapter that uses my own objects to draw the listitem.

From the other head I have a service that is gathering information realtime and every 0.1s my activity calls for the service information and than redraw listview by calling `myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

This is bad for me because the objects are really large and my UI thread freezes for some time probably less than 0.01s but still feels bad user experience.

The resource I'm updating is one circle that is drawn by custom drawing class in canvas. Does any of you know how to handle this problem ? Is there some way to update data and redraw listview without stopping my UI thread?

Comment: You're going to need to show some code to get some help.

Comment: Is your getView method optimized? You can reuse the views (passed as convertView)

Comment: No its not optimised is there any good tutorial for optimising it ?

Comment: I replied with an example

Comment: @BorisPawlowski For future reference, please put some effort into correctly typing your question and properly formatting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to reuse your convertView, like this:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    //inflate the view if it is null
    if( convertView == null ){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    //make the changes on your  convertView that are changed from row to row,
    //such as a text in a TextView
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I used this and it solved my problem. Thank you alot it was a problem I was thinkin about for more than a day. Thanks alot!!!